# Read Text input .docx .pdf File

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, module

**I want to read text in .docx .pdf File in JS environment.**

but No exist Reading Text Example from input File Object.
Some Other question's that Reading Text from File on path.

This is my code

**// template**

```
<v-file-input @change="uploadFile" />
```

**// script**

```
async uploadFile(file) {
  if (file != null) {
    // Extract file ext
    this.test_file = file;
    const ext = this.test_file.name.substring(this.test_file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, this.test_file.name.length).toLowerCase();

    // Process by ext
    switch (ext) {
      case 'txt':
        let text = await this.test_file.text();
        this.file_text = text;
        break;
      case 'docx':
        // How can I process docx file
        break;
      case 'pdf':
        // How can I process pdf file
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  } else {
    this.file_text = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript methods on their own do not enable you to directly parse document formats such as DOCX and PDF. Consider using a Document Library like LEADTOOLS which can parse text from these file types through a backend service. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor). For more details, check out the help topic [here](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/to/parsing-text-with-the-document-library.html)

Comment: Thank you for your interest! I'll take that into consideration.